# Print missing number from sequence

Tags: regex, powershell, sorting, scripting, range

I have a file called `test.txt` in which I have a sequence:

```
1
3
5
6
7
```

I would like to print the missing numbers and I found a [magic code](http://mow001.blogspot.com/2006/09/powershell-how-can-i-tell-whitch.html) that does it perfectly:

```
gc test.txt |% {$i = 1}{while ($i -lt $_){$i;$i++};$i++}
```

or this:

```
gc test.txt | sort {[int]$_} |% {$i = 1}{while ($i -lt $_){$i;$i++};$i++}
```

but I would like to print **ALL** the numbers:

- In **GREEN** the numbers that are in the list
- In **RED** the numbers that are missing from the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the file, start at the first number, end at the last, and output any number not in the file...

```
$TestFile = Get-Content Test.txt|Sort
[int]$TestFile[0]..[int]$TestFile[-1]|Where{$_ -notin $TestFile}
```

**Edit:** Oops, you want all numbers. That'll take a switch, one moment for an update.

```
$TestFile = Get-Content Test.txt|Sort
Switch([int]$TestFile[0]..[int]$TestFile[-1]){
    {$_ -notin $TestFile}{Write-Host "$_" -Fore Red;Continue}
   default {Write-Host "$_" -Fore Green}
}
```

Comment: Cool, it worked. BTW, what if my numbers are:
`0005048
0005049
0005409
0005410
0005411
0005412
0005413
0005414`
why they are all printing in **RED**?

Comment: Because my script is evaluating them as numbers, so it evaluates `5048 5049 5409 5410 5411 5412`. If you know that they are zero padded like that you could do something like `{"$_".Padleft(7,'0') -notin $TestFile}`

Answer (score 1):

Simply insert the `Write-Host -Fore red/green` in the right place:

```
gc test.txt | % {$i = 1}{while ($i -lt $_){write-host -Fore red $i;$i++};write-host -Fore green $i;$i++}
```

The same without aliases:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | ForEach-Object {$i = 1}{
   while ($i -lt $_){
     Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $i
     $i++
   }
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $i
   $i++
 }
```

[image]

Comment: since using the begin/process/end script blocks in a ForEach-Object command is so _very_ unusual [*grin*], i think you may want to use the parameter names instead of just "by position". i had to re-read the code several times since i was expecting a `|` to feed into the next step. [*blush*]